# Export signed APK with ProGuard error

Tags: android, export, libgdx, proguard, signed

I have seen a bunch of other similar post but still dont understand what is wrong with my code. I am trying to export a signed APK in android and get these errors:

```
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find superclass or interface android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent getParentActivityIntent()' in class android.app.Activity
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(android.content.Intent)' in class android.app.Activity
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean navigateUpTo(android.content.Intent)' in class android.app.Activity
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String parentActivityName' in class android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setSubText(java.lang.CharSequence)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setUsesChronometer(boolean)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setPriority(int)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(int,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification build()' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ShareCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String escapeHtml(java.lang.CharSequence)' in class android.text.Html
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilderJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.PendingIntent getActivities(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent[],int,android.os.Bundle)' in class android.app.PendingIntent
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'void startActivities(android.content.Intent[],android.os.Bundle)' in class android.content.Context
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean isActiveNetworkMetered()' in class android.net.ConnectivityManager
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider getAccessibilityNodeProvider(android.view.View)' in class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean performAccessibilityAction(android.view.View,int,android.os.Bundle)' in class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean hasTransientState()' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void setHasTransientState(boolean)' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void postInvalidateOnAnimation()' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void postOnAnimation(java.lang.Runnable)' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void postOnAnimationDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,long)' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'int getImportantForAccessibility()' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void setImportantForAccessibility(int)' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean performAccessibilityAction(int,android.os.Bundle)' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider getAccessibilityNodeProvider()' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getLabelFor()' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setLabelFor(int)' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void addChild(android.view.View,int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setSource(android.view.View,int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean isVisibleToUser()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setVisibleToUser(boolean)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean performAction(int,android.os.Bundle)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setMovementGranularities(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'int getMovementGranularities()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo obtain(android.view.View,int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo findFocus(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo focusSearch(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setParent(android.view.View,int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean isAccessibilityFocused()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setAccessibilityFocused(boolean)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setSource(android.view.View,int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.AssetManager getAssets()' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'java.io.File getFilesDir()' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'void setFullscreen(boolean)' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'void setContentView(android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.Object getSystemService(java.lang.String)' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Window getWindow()' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced method 'android.content.SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,int)' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream$1: can't find referenced method 'void finish()' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphicsDaydream: can't find referenced method 'android.view.WindowManager getWindowManager()' in class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidDaydream
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphicsDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphicsDaydream: can't find referenced class android.service.dreams.DreamService
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget$TargetOs
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget$TargetOs
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget$TargetOs
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget$TargetOs
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget$TargetOs
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.AntScriptGenerator
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.AntScriptGenerator
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildConfig
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildConfig
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.AntScriptGenerator
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget$TargetOs
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild: can't find referenced class com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.images.a: can't find referenced method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[] getCompoundDrawablesRelative()' in class android.widget.TextView
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.images.a: can't find referenced method 'void setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in class android.widget.TextView
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.ck: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.ck: can't find referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.es$b: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.es$b: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: there were 59 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] Warning: there were 55 unresolved references to program class members.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-02-18 21:20:35 - Bounce-android]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I am using LibGDX, google game service, in app billing and admob.

This is my progaurd:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}




-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 5):

Getting the proguard config right quite often wheels like a game of whack-a-mole. The first challenge is to get something working, then to polish the config so you force proguard to pull in as little as needed. Some things to try to get rid of warnings etc from your output, and possibly force proguard to keep more of the needed stuff:

```
# Libgdx stuff
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.*
-keep class com.badlogic.**
-keep public class android.content.Context
-keep public interface com.badlogic.gdx.Application
-keep public class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class java.lang.reflect.**
```

You get the idea..